# HTML Emails wIth Images - getting weird results in gmail

Tags: codeigniter, email, gmail

I am sending a multipart email through codeigniter using Amazon simple email service SMTP. I am providing a plain text version of the email along with the HTML version and google show the following [image: ][image:][image:} on all the emails. Is there any way to get around this?  I have seen this in any email I have received from another company so I figure I am doing something wrong. Any ideas?

To be clear the first few elements in the email are images, however this is no different than I have seen in many emails I receive as newsletters from other companies.

Let me know if you would like more detail, I don't really know were to keep for this one as any search or debugging has made any changes.

[image: When you recieve multible messages in a stack they collapse and this is the result]

Comment: You should elaborate on your question. Perhaps providing a raw view of the email (Show original in gmail) and some sample code.